# Complex Cron Scheduler

Tags: cron

Is it possible to start a Cron Scheduler every 30 days before the last day of each month?
I know how to trigger it every last days (not 30 days before that) using this expression for example:

> 0 0 9 L /1 *

Thanks for you help.

Best,
Ramzi

Comment: What cron are you using? `L` is non-standard. Usually, to do something that can't be expressed in the crontab entry itself, you have to do the check in the script that is called, i.e., call it every day and check if the current day is 30 days before the last day of the month.

Comment: Cron 6 I believe.
I can't really access the script. I'm using an app that can trigger cron schedulers where I can just put the expression in.